# React - Use enum object values inside switch case rendering

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to use enum object values inside switch case rendering in react?

Right now, my rendering looks like this.

```
const { type } = this.state;

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div>
      {
        1: <SettingTwo />,
        2: <SettingFour />,
        3: <SettingSix />,
      }[type]
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

This works fine, but I do not like these numbers just floating around without constants so I would like to use enum value from enum object that i imported in the top of my component. It would look something like this.

```
const { type } = this.state;

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div>
      {
        TYPES.TYPE_ONE: <SettingTwo />,
        TYPES.TYPE_TWO: <SettingFour />,
        TYPES.TYPE_THREE: <SettingSix />,
      }[type]
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

This does not work for me. Is that even possible, or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for doing a computed property name of an object literal is to use square brackets around the key:

```
{
  [TYPES.TYPE_ONE]: <SettingTwo />,
  [TYPES.TYPE_TWO]: <SettingFour />,
  [TYPES.TYPE_THREE]: <SettingSix />,
}
```

Comment: Oh, that was much easier then i thought. I wasnt able to find this anywhere. Thanks alot.